# Liferay and registration confirm page

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I have a question about Liferay (6.1.1 CE)

Is possibile to change the registration page confirm?
I have my registration confirm page and I would to redirect the user to this page after the registration procedure?
Is possibile this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create struts-action-hook to override struts action path "/login/create_account".

In your custom Struts Action class' processAction method you can have following code .

```
originalStrutsPortletAction.processAction(
            portletConfig, actionRequest, actionResponse);
        if(SessionErrors.isEmpty(actionRequest)){
            actionResponse.sendRedirect("/web/xyz/registrationconfirmation");
        }
```

Hope this would help.

Link to example code:[sample-struts-action-hook](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/master/hooks/sample-struts-action-hook)

Comment: Tnx Pankaj Kathiriya for you reply.I'm new in Liferay..is possibile to have a pratical example?